# Adapter is abstract cannot be instantiated on RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to view data on RecyclerView.i got an error on from these two lines.

```
 `mAdapter = new Adapter(stu);`
```

in this line getting Error on Adapter is abstract
I'm a beginner of android .can someone helps me fix this problem. view the data on RecyclerView. my database name is StudentDB it has a table name record.record table data I need to view on RecyclerView.

I attached the full codes below

view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rs1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view1">    
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

view.java

```
public class view1 extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view1);

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    final Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from record", null);
    int id = c.getColumnIndex("id");
    final int name = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    final int age = c.getColumnIndex("age");
    c.moveToFirst();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rs1);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    final ArrayList<student> stud = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            student stu = new student();
            stu.id = c.getString(id);
            stu.name = c.getString(name);
            stu.age = c.getString(age);
            stud.add(stu);

        } while (c.moveToNext());

        //you need to add the Student object stu not the ArrayList Object stud
        if (stud != null && stud.size() > 0) {
            mAdapter = new Adapter(stud);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Student Class**

```
public class student {

    String id;
    String name;
    String age;
    String titles;
}
```

Comment: can you confirm that data inside stu is not null??

Comment: no it has a data sir.i tried on listview working fine

Comment: i don't know how to view on RecyclerView

Comment: can you post the item xml

Comment: i alwary post above the file sir

Comment: Post your Adapter class for recyclerview

Comment: `Adapter` class ??

Answer (score 3):

you are adding student object to adapter . you need to add student list to adapter . change your code like this

```
        final List<student> stud = new ArrayList();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                student stu = new student();
                stu.id = c.getString(id);
                stu.name = c.getString(name);
                stu.age = c.getString(age);

                stud.add(stu); // add your object to list

            } while (c.moveToNext());

              mAdapter = new Adapter(stud);
              recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Should be `stud` list object to adapter, not `stu`.

Comment: stud.add(stu); variable stud might not be intilalize

Answer (score 0):

Try setting adapter like this,

```
final List<student> stud  = new ArrayList();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            student stu = new student();
            stu.id = c.getString(id);
            stu.name = c.getString(name);
            stu.age = c.getString(age);
            stud.add(stu); 
        } while (c.moveToNext());
          mAdapter = new Adapter(stud);
          layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Also change the layout to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view1">    
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rs1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

Comment: again error sir  Adapter is abstract cannot be instantiated  this line  mAdapter = new Adapter(stud);   and           stud.add(stu);      stud.add(stu); variable stud might not be intilalize

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the adaptor within the`do while loop`. and refactoring your code is needed,creating `custom adaptor`....taking out the database call from the activity `view1` class to it's own class. and you need to be comfortable with generics and inner classes to work on custom adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 final ArrayList<student> stud = new ArrayList<>();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                student stu = new student();
                stu.id = c.getString(id);
                stu.name = c.getString(name);
                stu.age = c.getString(age);
                stud.add(stu);

           } while (c.moveToNext());

           //you need to add the Student object stu not the ArrayList Object stud
            if(stud!=null&&stud.size()>0){
               DummyAdapter mAdapter = new DummyAdapter(this,stud);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
               }
```

**create a new Adapter class like this**

```
public class DummyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DummyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<student> studentArraylist;

    public DummyAdapter(Context mContext,ArrayList<student> studentArraylist) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.studentArraylist  = studemtArraylist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //add your layout design file here
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.fragment_packing_dummy, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Student stud = studentArraylist.get(position);
  //perform your rest functionality
    holder.txt.settext(stud.name)

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentArraylist.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      //access your layout ids here for example
       TextView txt;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot be resove the symbol stu error displayed sir

Comment: mAdapter = new Adapter(stud);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); these two lines get error  Adapter is abstract

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
final ArrayList<student> stud=new ArrayList<>();
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            student stu = new student();
            stu.id = c.getString(id);
            stu.name = c.getString(name);
            stu.age = c.getString(age);
            //you need to add the Student object stu not the 
          //ArrayList Object stud
          stud.add(stu);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
            mAdapter = new Adapter(stud);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
 }
```